# Cassandra queries performance, ranges

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I'm quite new with Cassandra, and I was wondering if there would be any impact in performance if a query is asked with "date = '2015-01-01'" or "date >= '2015-01-01' AND date <= '2015-01-01'".

The only reason I want to use the ranges like that is because I need to make multiple queries and I want to have them prepared (as in prepared statements). This way the prepared statements number is cut by half.

The keys used are ((key1, key2), date) and (key1, date, key2) in the two tables I want to use this. The query for the first table is similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE key1 = val1
    AND key2 = val2
    AND date >= date1 AND date <= date2
```

Comment: Is this a row query or a column query?  If it's a row query, what row partitioner are you using?

Comment: It's a row query, we're using Murmur3Partitioner and the key is (key1, date, key2) in one table and ((key1, key2), date) in another. I wanted to use something similar to
`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE key1 = val1 AND key2 = val2 AND date >= date1 AND date <= date1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `PRIMARY KEY (key1, date, key2)` that type of query just isn't possible.  If you do, you'll see an error like this:

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column
>   "key2" cannot be restricted (preceding column "date" is either not
>   restricted or by a non-EQ relation)"

Cassandra won't allow you to filter by a PRIMARY KEY component if the preceding column(s) are filtered by anything other than the equals operator.

On the other hand, your queries for `PRIMARY KEY ((key1, key2), date)` will work and perform well.  The reason, is that Cassandra uses the clustering key(s) (`date` in this case) to specify the on-disk sort order of data within a partition.  As you are specifying partition keys (`key1` and `key2`) your result set will be sorted by `date`, allowing Cassandra to satisfy your query by performing a continuous read from the disk.

Just to test that out, I'll even run two queries on a table with a similar key, and turn [tracing](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html) on:

```
SELECT * FROM log_date2 WHERe userid=1001 
AND time > 32671010-f588-11e4-ade7-21b264d4c94d 
AND time < a3e1f750-f588-11e4-ade7-21b264d4c94d;
```

Returns 1 row and completes in 4068 microseconds.

```
SELECT * FROM log_date2 WHERe userid=1001 
AND time=74ad4f70-f588-11e4-ade7-21b264d4c94d;
```

Returns 1 row and completes in 4001 microseconds.

Comment: I don't mean exactly this query for all the tables, this is for one of them, I will edit the question if you'd like. I'm interested only in the fact that I'm using "<=" and ">=" instead of "=", and if it will impact the performance at all.

Comment: @mar No need to edit.  The 2nd part of my answer addresses that.  If you are range-querying by your clustering key(s), then your read operation should be quite fast.  Shouldn't be noticeably different from filtering on date once with =

Comment: @Aaron How many rows did you have in log_date2 when you tested it?